# MONOGRAM AAC Encoder generates file with no audio

Tags: audio, directshow, capture, aac, encoder

I have tried to capture audio from live streaming by using audio capture device with MONOGRAM

AAC Encoder downloaded from http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/2007/12/11/free-aac-encoder-filter/,

but it generates audio file with 1kb of size without audio.

Can anyone tell me the reason of this?

Thank You.

Comment: AAC Encoder delivers compressed audio stream, not files. Post more detail on your encoding topology.